# How can I remove similar lines from a text file (image listing) using batch, Jscript (JREPL ?) or vBScript?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

The environment is WindowsXP (possibly upgrading to Windows7 soon).
I am allowed to run scripts but NOT allowed to install tools.

Pure batch has generally failed due to performance issues or 'special' characters (such as the exclamation mark).

FINDSTR has generally failed because it finds ALL instances of a search string, rather than just the first match.

The closest solutions I have found are those mentioned by dbenham at:
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=39534#p39534

My text file typically contains a (2MB) list of images (most recent version first) per folder (numero-alphabetically), usually created via command line:   dir *.jpg /o:-d /b /s > test.txt

I only want to keep the lines showing the most recent version of each image (marked with asterisks below).

Essentially, I only want to keep the first line for each image-id (the eight characters before #).

The order of the listed images must NOT change, because the list is used to run a slideshow:

```
D:\2016 London\2016-01-02 DSCN2111#227 bridge top.jpg   *
D:\2016 London\2016-01-02 DSCN2111#211 bridge top.jpg
D:\2016 London\2016-01-02 DSCN2111#110 bridge top.jpg
D:\2016 Paris\2016-01-01 imag1233#121 restaurant.jpg    *
D:\2016 Paris\2016-01-01 imag1233#110 restaurant.jpg
D:\2016 Paris\2016-01-01 P0001232#110 procession¿.jpg   *
D:\2016 Paris\2016-01-01 DSC_1231#111 skyline^05am.jpg  *
D:\2016 Paris\2016-01-01 DSC_1231#110 skyline^05am.jpg
D:\2016 Paris\2016-01-01 DSCN1230#310 fountain {!}.jpg  *
D:\2016 Paris\2016-01-01 DSCN1230#224 fountain {!}.jpg
D:\2016 Paris\2016-01-01 DSCN1230#110 fountain {!}.jpg
```

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ooops! Sorry, didn't mean to offend. I am a total newbie to forums of any kind and did read extensively before posting. I believe this is relevant to many others and have been trying to solve this problem for many months and wanted to avoid flooding your well-organised site with hundreds of links and hopelessly inadequate code written by me.  I am afraid my pensioner-brain is now probably passed its use-by date for the degree of concentration required to succeed!  That said, I have edited the post. If I am breaking rules please delete and I will continue to struggle & manually edit the files.

Comment: I see you can't install tools, but let me ask if you happen to have NotePad++ installed. It would help A LOT.

Comment: No, not at the moment, sorry.  I am also unsure if Notepad++ can be called from a batch file?  I mean called with arguments so that the process is somewhat automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking you at your word that the list is already sorted such that like named files are already contiguous, and the most recent one is always listed first.

It shouldn't be hard to write a dedicated VBS or JScript script, but perhaps it is a bit easier to use JREPL with a bit of user supplied JScript as follows:

```
jrepl "^(.+?)#.*$" "if ($1==prev) {false} else {prev=$1;$0}" /jmatch /jbeg "prev=''" /f test.txt
```

Comment: YES, your JREPL solution is good when called from a batch file thus:
Call jrepl "^(.+?)#.*$" "if ($1==prev) {false} else {prev=$1;$0}" /jmatch /jbeg "prev=''" /f test.txt /o best-of.txt 

I am very grateful for your assistance here and for your JREPL.BAT, which is now a crucial tool in maintaining a large personal collection of (mainly bird) images from around the world.  Is there a way I can pm you, should you be interested in the various steps of maintenance, or token gratitude, comments re your flute etc?